# How to know how many people got a tag badge

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-badges

Is there a way to know how many people got a tag badge? Like for Java, JavaScript, Spring Framework, etc.

I know we get to see how many people got a normal badge, but what about tag badges?

Answer (score 15):

Simple. If you go to the page in the help center [that lists all the badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) and click on the Bronze, Silver or Gold Tag badges.

[image]

That would bring up a list of all tags for that tier:

[image]

Furthermore, if you click on one of them, like the [bronze .htaccess badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/600/htaccess), you can see a list of people who got it.

Comment: how can I see the gold badge holders of a language specific tag? I can't find those in there. e.g. see gold badge holders for `swift`, `java`?

Comment: @Honey I know of only two ways: 1. Find the tag and then click on [Top users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkWt1.png) and then work out if they actually have the badge or 2. Pick one of those top users, find the [badge in their profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVwj1.png) and click it *twice*. Once for the information about when it was awarded to them, but there you can [click it again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWqVy.png) to find everyone is has been awarded to.

Comment: @Honey I just realized there is a third way. Use the list of all badges as this post says. Click on the [general gold one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izKzu.png) and search for "swift" :)

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the screenshots. I initially tried your link, but didn't figure it out. Then comments made it clear. Option3 was the best, Then option2. Option 1 was not ideal

Comment: @Honey It's not my post, and I do not have editing privileges on meta, since meta doesn't have suggested edits :) Option 2 needs Option 1, no? I agree that it would be better to add these images into the post though.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the [answer from Memor-X](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364636/578411) you could use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help). For example this query does what you want:

```sql
select tagname
     , case class 
       when 1 then 'gold' 
       when 2 then 'silver' 
       when 3 then 'bronze' 
       end [class]
     , count(*) [# awarded]
from tags t 
inner join badges b on b.name = t.tagname and b.tagbased = 1
where tagname = ##tagname:string?java##
group by tagname
       , class
```

When run today your result for Java will be:

[image: java gold 641 java silver 1856 java bronze 7551]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday from 03:00 UTC onwards.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).